# how can i pass a view via intent in android

Tags: android, view, cursor, broadcastreceiver, android-cursoradapter

i am using a list that is pupolated with a custom adaptor that extends CursorAdaptor, i would like to download images while doing it and place them in the adapter layout, i use intentService to download the image i get it back with a reciver, now i have my image in my onRecive finction but i am buffled as to how i can place it in a view that is in the new CursorAdapter, anybody knows?

the Cursor Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {


        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.Places.NAME));
        String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.Places.ADDRESS));
        String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.Places.TYPE));
        float rating = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.Places.RATING));
        String icon = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContractPlaces.Places.ICON));

        TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView addressView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView typeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
        TextView ratingView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);

        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        nameView.setText(name);
        addressView.setText(address);
        typeView.setText("Type: "+type);
        ratingView.setText("Rating: "+String.valueOf(rating));


        // iconView - this is where i would like to place tha image from the reciver    

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cursor_layout, parent, false);
        }


class ImageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bitmap b = intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
//this is the image i would like to place in the view "iconView"

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its being a lengthy process to download the image in Intent Service and get that image to adapter class. If you are Interested I have a solution for you.

Use Universal Image Loader library for downloading image. You need not worry about anything. The library itself consists of so many in-built methods. you can use them.

see [`this`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) thread for using Universal Image Loader

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to pass any data type directly through the `intent` except `boolean`, `integer`, `string`, `Char`, `Float` and the other primitive data types.

Passing any other type will be via `parcelable` `intent`. Using `parcelable` you can pass any `object` whatever its type. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/1364896) of the `parcelable` and how to use it

**OR**

Create a public method called `newInstance(Object o)` and in this method call your default constructor and set your object value as following:

```
public MyActivity newInstance(MyObject o){
    MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
    this.myObject = o;
    return activity;
}
```

Comment: i think you don't say many data type like char, float and other. and you forgot serializable object too.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan, yes, but I mean the primitives data types but I will add it thank you